Changing The Axis That Vector3.Slerp's Arc Happens On
I am using Vector3.Slerp to move a boomerang from the player to a target in an arc, and then back to the player.
It's currently working, but not the way that I want it to.
My issue is that I would like the arc to happen in the Z-Axis, rather than the Y-Axis. (So that it behaves more like a boomerang rather than a lobbed projectile)
Here's a visual example of what I'm looking to accomplish:


----
Here is the code I'm using:
    private IEnumerator ThrowBoomerang()
{
    // Set the start and end position of the boomerang
    _startPoint = Boomerang.transform.position;
    _endPoint = Enemy.transform.position;

    // The time that the boomerang's journey starts at
    var startTime = Time.time;

    while(Boomerang.transform.position != _endPoint)
    {
        // The center of the boomerang's arc
        Vector3 center = (_startPoint - _endPoint) * 0.5f;

        // Move the center a bit downwards to make the arc
        center -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

        // Move the boomerang in an arc relative to the center
        Vector3 startRelCenter = _startPoint - center;
        Vector3 endRelCenter = _endPoint - center;

        // The fraction of the journey that has happened so far
        float fracComplete = (Time.time - startTime) / _journeyTime;

        // Move the boomerang to the calculated position and add center
        Boomerang.transform.position = Vector3.Slerp(startRelCenter, endRelCenter, fracComplete);
        Boomerang.transform.position += center;

        yield return null;
    }
}


I was under the impression that changing the center's direction would change the axis that the arc happens on. So, I changed this line:
    // Move the center a bit downwards to make the arc
    center -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0);

to this:
    // Move the center a bit downwards to make the arc
    center -= new Vector3(0, 0, 1);

I also tried using a variable like this:
    // Move the center a bit downwards to make the arc
    center -= new Vector3(0, 0, Offset);

But no matter what I change the vector to, the arc always happens in the Y-Axis.
Any help would be immensely appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Slerp will always happen in the plane containing the start, end, and center (origin) points. The trouble is that you're computing your center point incorrectly, treating it as a displacement when it needs to be an absolute point in space. You want to add start and end before dividing by two to get their average, not subtract them. You should also avoid calling the position setter more times than you need to, by adding the center back in the line with the slerp, rather than as its own separate step.

The SE god himself has graced me . So, I changed (_startPoint - _endPoint) to (_startPoint + _endPoint) and completely removed this line after center -= new Vector3(0, 1, 0). This gave me a horizontal arc just like I wanted! Though, I'd be lying if I said I had any idea why this made it work. I'd love to understand this fix because I need a second arc opposite to the first for when the boomerang returns to the player.

I'll write something up once I've made some dinner, if no one beats me to it.

To explain why the original code didn't work, let's assume everything is sitting on the Z = 0 plane for simplicity, and look at an XY cross-section. Here's what happens if we try to throw a boomerang from a start point at (2, 6, 0) to an end point at (6, 8, 0):

Start - End gives us a vector that stores the displacement from End to Start. When we try to divide that vector by 2 and use it as the position of our "center" of rotation, we get a point that's half the boomerang's travel from the origin - nowhere near the center of our two points!
If our start and end are significantly above the origin, and relatively close to the same elevation, then this will give us a "center" point much lower on the y axis. That means that even after we shift that point a little on the Z, the plane joining these three points is going to be pretty close to vertical, and so a Slerp using this center is going to look more like an overhead lob.
If we instead add start and end before dividing by two, then we're computing the average of their values. That gives us a true center, exactly in the middle of the two points. Slightly shifting that point along the z axis will then make a plane that's mostly horizontal (apart from any pitch due to the difference in elevation between the start and end).
Myself though, I'd be inclined to use a little trig to position the boomerang, for more precise control over the shape and timing of the movement:
private IEnumerator ThrowBoomerang(float durationSeconds)
{
    // Set the start and end position of the boomerang
    var start = Boomerang.transform.position;
    var end = Enemy.transform.position;

    var halfTravel = (start - end) * 0.5f;

    var center = end + halfTravel;

    // Make an orientation where Y points from end to start,
    // Y is as close to vertical as it can be, and X is horizontal.
    var coordinateFrame = Quaternion.LookRotation(halfTravel);
    // This lets us design an arc in the XZ plane for simplicity, 
    // and transform it to match our actual start and end.

    float majorAxis = halfTravel.magnitude;

    // _ellipseRatio = 1 is a perfectly circular arc.
    // Values closer to zero = less off-axis movement (more direct).
    // Negate to flip clockwise / counter-clockwise orbit directon.
    float minorAxis = Mathf.Min(_ellipseRatio * majorAxis, _maxOffAxis);
    // The _maxOffAxis parameter lets you limit how far wide the boomerang
    // can sweep, in case it looks silly when start and end are far apart.

    float speed = 1f/durationSeconds;

    for (float t = 0; t < 1f; t += Time.deltaTime * speed) {
        // If you want, you can apply a non-linear function 
        // or animation curve here, to give the boomerang more
        // hang time in the first half of the arc and make the
        // return more snappy, or add a hit pause at the impact...   
        float angle = t * Mathf.PI * 2f;

        // Trace an ellipse in the XZ plane.
        var pos = new Vector3(
                      Mathf.Sin(angle) * minorAxis, 
                      0,
                      Mathf.Cos(angle) * majorAxis
        );

        // Transform back into world space and apply.
        Boomerang.transform.position = center + coordinateFrame * pos;

        yield return null;
    }

    // Ensure we complete our return (making up any
    // loose change left over at the end of the loop)
    Boomerang.transform.postion = start;
}

Note that this function does both the outgoing and return arc in one pass. If you want just one arc, remove the * 2f; after Mathf.PI to only traverse 180°, and change the fixup line at the bottom to use end instead of start.

Oh, wow. This was extremely helpful! Thank you so much for not just explaining that, but for also providing a more robust solution.
